# Which concrete mix is better for these particular countertop dimensions?

Tags: concrete, kitchens, kitchen-counters, countertops

**Background**:

- Been going back and forth about which option to go with so thought I should ask the community what you think and which concrete mix is best.
- Dimension for each slab are listed in the table.
- As you can see, opting for 2" thick countertops.
- Listing three options *that are available to me in my area*.

[image]

Of these options, which is best?

1. [Quikrete 5000](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-80-lb-High-Early-Strength-Concrete-Mix-100700/100318486?MERCH=REC-_-SearchPLPHorizontal1_rr-_-NA-_-100318486-_-N)
2. [Quikrete Countertop mix](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-80-lb-Commercial-Grade-Countertop-Mix-1106-80/202832660)
3. [Spec Mix Premium Concrete Countertop Mix](https://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/concrete-cement-masonry/bagged-concrete-cement-mortar/concrete-countertop-mix/p-1444445323295-c-5648.htm?tid=-3553270389891291206)

1) is the most economical, but worried it's not the right product for the job unless maybe I add PVA fibers? 2) Is supposed to be made for countertops but it's hard to get in my area and I haven't heard great things about it. 3) Is pretty expensive and would cost me close to $465 before tax.

Answer (score 1):

Just being pedantic: PVA is glue; polypropylene is the term you're looking for.

Cheng, in "Concrete Countertops" isbn 1-56158-484-3 states (p. 98) that Quikcrete 5000 is fine if you add fibers, water reducer, and pigments. If you don't already have the book, get it.

As a general tip regarding concrete (or any mix-ables, for that matter), buy more than you think you'll need and be prepared to return excess. There's nothing worse than being in the middle of a job and realizing that you're short.